# PyQt5: Problems naming a row after using insertRow()

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to create a button that adds a row to a table (QtTableWidget) and uses a dialog box to ask for the name, and I have hit a big problem (seemingly a flaw within PyQt).

By adding a row using the insertRow() function the row header automatically has a value of none, which then means you cannot use the verticalHeaderItem(rowPosition).setText(...) on the row Header as it cannot set the text of an item with value none.

The relevant code is here:

```
def RenameRow(self, i, name):
    self.tab1table.verticalHeaderItem(i).setText(name)


def DatabaseAddRow(self):
    text, ok = QInputDialog.getText(self, "Row Entry", 'Please Enter A Row Name:', QLineEdit.Normal, 'e.g. ECN 776')
    if ok and text != '':
        rowPosition = self.tab1table.rowCount()
        self.tab1table.insertRow(rowPosition)
        self.RenameRow(rowPosition, text)
```

Any Ideas how to get around this or maybe methods I do not know about?

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to solve this myself just after asking this after wasting half a day on this problem, such is life.  The solution to the problem is to assign an empty item to the header and then rename it, the implementation is here:

```
def RenameRow(self, i, name, table):
    item = QTableWidgetItem()
    table.setVerticalHeaderItem(i, item)
    item = table.verticalHeaderItem(i)
    item.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", name))
```

Comment: Or just: `table.setVerticalHeaderItem(i, QTableWidgetItem(name))`. And note that the `translate` call is almost certainly redundant. It doesn't really make sense to use it on runtime variables, because the translation process works by *static analysis*. The only way that `name` could be translated properly, is if it happened to match a literal string that had been correctly translated elsewhere in your source code.

Comment: Ah ok I wasn't sure what translate did but someone else seemed to use it so I copied it blindly, thanks